# how to add jquery animation to dynamically created div element in javascript

Tags: jquery, html

How do i add jquery amination property to a dynamically created div element in javascript. Could someone please help me with this, how do i pass div's id as selector to jquery function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a fiddle for that. Or post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the div with this..

```
$("body").on(click,"#selector",function(){
    #code...
});

or

$("body").find("#selector").(ur event)
```

Comment: What if i want to add animation to multiple div elements having unique id's. And am not using any events am simply calling by method..is that possible? Please correct me if am wrong am very new to javascript and jquery.

Comment: you can have their ids in a pattern of increasing counter and for every div you can increase your counter acccordingly